# How to use Dompdf on Phalcon? Why do I get Permission Denied?

Tags: phalcon, dompdf, permission-denied, chroot

I'm trying to make Dompdf work on Phalcon, but I'm getting an error at the time of using the $dompdf->load_html_file($html) command, at that point i'm getting the following message: [The file could not be found under the directory specified by Options::chroot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkuId.jpg)

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once $config->application->dompdfDir.'/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{

public function indexAction()
{

}

public function pdfAction()
{
    // set the default timezone to use

    date_default_timezone_set('America/El_Salvador');
    $fechaHoy = date('d/m/Y'); // H:i:s');
    $miembro = "Some Name";
    $monto = "20.00";
    $meses = "Enero 2016, Febrero 2016";
    $firma = "Other Name";

    $html = 
    '<table border="0" align="center">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
            <td align="left">Imagen</td>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">TESORERIA DE OCDS<br>STELLA MARIS</td>
            <td align="right">Fecha: '.$fechaHoy.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td colspan="4">Recibi de '.$miembro.' la cantidad de $'.$monto.'<br>
            en concepto de cuota mensual de los siguientes meses: <br>'.$meses.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td><td colspan="2">F. '.$firma.'</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>';

    $html = '<html>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
        @page {margin: 10px }
    -->
    </style><body>'.$html.'</body></html>';

     $dompdf = new DomPdf();
     $newChroot = APP_PATH . '\\public\\temp';
     //echo $newChroot;
     $dompdf->set_option('chroot', $newChroot);
     echo $dompdf->get_option('chroot');
     $dompdf->load_html_file($html);

     // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
     $dompdf->setPaper(array(0,0,132,408), 'landscape');

     // Render the HTML as PDF
     $dompdf->render();

     // Get the generated PDF file contents
     $pdf = $dompdf->output();

     // Output the generated PDF to Browser
     $dompdf->stream();
}

}
```

As you can see I have even changed the chroot to another one to see if that solved the issue assuming the problem was actually referencing the app folder for Phalcon.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're generating the HTML inside your script you should use `$dompdf->load_html($html)`. You would use the `load_html_file` to load an actual file (either on the local file system or on a remote system).

Comment: Thank! that was such a rookie mistake. But now that I changed that and removed the chroot part that I had I was able to generate a pdf file but when trying to open it I got an error: Adobe... could not open 'document.pdf' because it is either not a supporte file type or because the file has been damaged. How to I solve that?

Comment: First thing I would do is open the generated PDF in a text editor (Notepad, TextEdit, vi). If your site has output buffering enabled it's possible that PHP threw some notices that got captured in the PDF stream. Usually they're right at the top of the file before the PDF source.

Comment: Thanks again, this is what I'm getting: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Phalcon PHP Framework</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            %PDF-1.3

Comment: It looks like Phalcon is capturing the output and inserting into your site layout as if it's a regular HTML document. I'm not familiar with Phalcon, but based on [this discussion](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/985/generating-pdf-file-in-phalcon-framework) you might just add `$this->view->disable();` to your PDF action.

Comment: Awesome! you're great, I should've known that, I've been using Phalcon enough not to be failing on things like this.